# I cant view my form inputs in the django database

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-admin, django-database

I am a learner in django. i have created my first form, but when i input data i dont see it in my database but see in in my shell. I have rechecked my code but it seem fine, yet still it wont save in my code in the database.
Please help me out here.Thanks.

#### Model:

```py
from django.db import models

class Login(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    second_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.EmailField()
    password = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

#### View:

```py
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Login
from .forms import login_form

def homeview(request):
    return HttpResponse("<h1>Hello There</h1>")

def login_view(request):
    form = login_form(request.POST or None)

    if form.is_valid:
        form.save
    context = {
        "form":form
    }   

    return render(request, "login.html", context)
```

#### Template:

```html
{% block content %}

<form action="" method="GET">{% csrf_token %}

{{form.as_p}}
<input type="submit" value="Login"/> 
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

#### Form:

```py
from django import forms
from .models import Login

class login_form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Login
        fields = [
            "first_name",
            "second_name",
            "email",
            "password"
        ]
```

Comment: In the template you specify the method to be GET while in the view you expect it to be a POST. You better make it a POST https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following lines are incorrect:

```py
    if form.is_valid:
        form.save
```

Currently the `if` will always return `True` because `.is_valid` returns the bound method.

You need to call `is_valid` -> `form.is_valid()`

Same for `form.save`. You would only return the bound method `save`, but you don't call it.

These lines would look like this:

```py
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
```

Furthermore: In your template the used `method` for your form is `GET` but you are accessing `request.POST`. You need to change either one of them to the other method, e.g. `method="POST"`.

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked. Thanks a lot. was stressed and was almost quiting all of it.

Comment: @moseskabuye Please consider [marking the answer as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it solved your problem.